# wordpress plugin translation

Tags: wordpress, gettext

I have a plugin (lets say that it is called my_plugin), in which I generated the .po file, and subsequently the .mo file. I saved the files in a folder called languages. I called the files my_plugin-en_US.po and my_plugin-en_US.mo.

Summary of structure:
plugins (dir)
--my_plugin (dir)
----languages (dir)
------my_plugin-en_US.po (file)
------my_plugin-en_US.mo (file)

The translation still does not show (the original plugin is not in English).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you called [load_plugin_textdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain)?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, your link helped. You can post it as an answer and I will mark it if you like

Comment: Awesome - thanks.  Happy to add any further detail you think will help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly load the translation with [load_plugin_textdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain).